# Why are tables bad rather than CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Why are tables so hated over CSS? And why doesn't CSS have all the features that tables do?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: They're not bad.  They're just bad for page layouts.  Tables are meant for data.

Comment: Tables and CSS are two different things. Your second question is nonsense (and your first, to a degree, is a misconception).

Comment: Not sure why the winning close vote was "not constructive" when a very, very well-known and high-scoring duplicate was found. Oh well, added the link for great justice.

Comment: Yes, this kind of question is not constructive, but since a duplicate was found...

Answer (score 2):

here you have 13 reason why css is better that tables. 
http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/13-reasons-why-css-is-superior-to-tables-in-website-design/

you should google a little before asking.
:p

Comment: This answer comes up in google now.

Comment: The link is expired, rendering this answer meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of semantics. Tables would be more appropriate to format tabular data.

Also, for the sake of readability, tables can be rather cumbersome to anyone who may have to come along to work on a site afterward.